# R: displaying color depending on percentage in plot

Tags: r, plot, colors, scale

i have the following plot:

```
p<- plot(c(0,1),c(0,1), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)+
  rect(0,0,.5,.5, col = "green")+
  rect(.5,0,1,.5, col = "orange")+
  rect(0,.5,.5,1, col = "yellow")+
  rect(.5,.5,1,1, col = "red")
```

however instead of manually imputing the colors to the rectangles i would like to have a function [0,1] -> colors, where i have a value between 0 and 1 and it colors the boxes depending on the value. e.g:

```
 (...)
 rect(0,0,.5,.5, col = function(0.3))+
 (...)
```

Comment: You can create a vector `mycolours <- c(‘green’,’orange’,’yellow’,’red’)` and then reference it `mycolours[1]`. You can also use functions like `colorRampPalette` to make gradients.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am looking for a solution like colorRamp. Could you give me a working example for colorRampPalette?

Comment: I've written an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres one way to create that function

```
PercentageColour <- function(x){colorRampPalette(c('green','orange','yellow','red'))(101)[round(x*100)+1]}

p<- plot(c(0,1),c(0,1), type= "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", axes = FALSE)+
   rect(0,0,.5,.5, col = PercentageColour(0.01))+
   rect(.5,0,1,.5, col = PercentageColour(0.25))+
   rect(0,.5,.5,1, col = PercentageColour(0.356))+
   rect(.5,.5,1,1, col = PercentageColour(0.95))
```

Where `colorRampPalette(colours)` creates the ramp, `(100)` specifies how many steps you want in the ramp, and `[round(x*100)]` is rounding your percentage input and converting it to the indexed values for reference.

You can also use some of the default colour ramps if you don't want to make your own. Try `rainbow` or `heat.colors` for example

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what i am looking for. however is it possible to create a continuous scale from 0 - 1?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, the function I've provided will accept any value from 0-1 (I've edited it such that it accepts 0 now). It just creates 100 bins based in that range. What specifically are you looking for?

Comment: your answer works. i was under the impression, that e.g. 0.2384 would work, but as the function creates bins, it works perfectly. thanks for your time and have a nice day!